# Cannot find declaration for OFFlickrAPIRequestDelegate

Tags: xcode, sharekit

Building my app in XCode fails:

Cannot find protocol declaration for 'OFFlickrAPIRequestDelegate'.

I've come as far as understanding that the issue is caused by Sharekit. Can someone please point me to the solution? Do I need to update submodule, but how?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You need to upgrade the ShareKit!